# Select rows in SQL that follow certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sas

I want to select rows that follow the following conditions in SQL.

Table Name:

```
   Codes_and_Numbers
```

I have the following dataset:

```
Code_Name   Num_1   Num_2
   A        10      12
   A        10      10
   A        10      10
   B        17      17
   B        17      17
   B        17      17
   B        17      17
   C        21      25
   C        21      23
```

I want to select the rows where Num_1 and Num_2 **are not** equal, however if on another row with the same Code_Name, Num_1 and Num_2 **are** equal then I don't want to select any of the rows under that Code_Name.

In the dataset above, this would mean only the 2 rows for C would be selected. As A has two rows with equal Num_1 and Num_2 and all of B rows are equal.

Comment: You want this? Or your teacher?

Comment: try to 'GROUP BY' your codes

Comment: So what's the expected result? (With the sample data as specified.)

Comment: @dmaij Does it matter if it's an assignment? It's still a real question, though attempt and expected result should've been included.

Comment: @artm, still it's worth mentioning. If it's a school work I prefer assisting OP finding the query, instead of just giving it away. OP will learn much more that way!

Comment: @artm Yes, it does, You are letting somebody else do your homework. If you try first and post what you have done sofar, you might have found the answer instead of bothering people.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you really using MS SQL Server, SAS and MySQL here?

Comment: @dmaij It is not school work, I am no longer at school and I am very new to SQL (and stackoverflow)

Comment: @jarlh I am doing SQL queries inside SAS.

Comment: Ok, my bad, but the question profiles quite like a homework assignment. Try to show what you've tried already next time to avoid this conversation. The answer is given, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Code_Name, Num_1, Num_2
FROM Codes_and_Numbers AS t1
WHERE t1.Num_1 <> t1.Num_2 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Codes_and_Numbers AS t2
                  WHERE t1.Code_Name = t2.Code_Name AND
                        t2.Num_1 = t2.num_2)
```